# Transition causes repainting of all following elements in grid layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, grid-layout

I would like to know the reason and the solution to the excessive repaint in the following HTML document. On Chrome, repaint can be visualized in `devtool -> rendering panel -> Paint flashing`. The problem itself has many ways to workaround, but I'm more interested in the reason why such repaint happens.

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".contents > img")) {
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() { this.classList.add("easy-in-out", "scale-150", "scale", "z-20"); });
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() { this.classList.remove("easy-in-out", "scale-150", "scale", "z-20"); });
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2" style="width: 410px">
  <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

(However, it seems that Chrome is not capable of showing "Paint flashing" inside the iframe, so I also provide the minimal single-file snippet below, or online at https://jjyyxx.github.io/grid-repaint/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="width: 410px;">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
    <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
    <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
    <div class="contents"><img class="relative transition p-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".contents > img")) {
      el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() { this.classList.add("easy-in-out", "scale-150", "scale", "z-20"); });
      el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() { this.classList.remove("easy-in-out", "scale-150", "scale", "z-20"); });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you `mouseleave` one image element, the fading transition will cause all its following image elements repainted. With many images or some large images, this behavior causes frame drop.

Since the layout did not change, in my opinion, only the hovered element should get repainted. If  `style="will-change: scale;"` is added to `div`s with selector `.contents > img`, this desired behavior could be achieved. But the documentation suggests that using `will-change` extensively is not a best practice.

**Reproducible on Chrome v120.0.6099.72.** Removing `relative` on image elements seems to fix this repaint.

Comment: You see JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The `mouseleave` has no effect on other elements on my local machine or EC2 instance. Transitions work just fine. As an aside please [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). Do you have other code you haven't shared that may impact event listeners?

Comment: @jQueeny Thanks for your attention. I've shorten the snippet and provide more information. Let me know if you still have difficulty in reproducing the problem. It is also possible to verify it online with https://www.browserling.com/, inputting  https://jjyyxx.github.io/grid-repaint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`transform-gpu`](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/transform#hardware-acceleration) to all the `<img>` tags:

```html
<img class="relative transition p-1 transform-gpu" src="">
```

This will put them in separate layers and will use GPU for transformations.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. However, on my side, I was also able to workaround by applying image optimization (this boosts load time as well). Now I am more interested in knowing why a certain combination of CSS leads to such repaint. Is it potentially a bug of Chrome?

Comment: It is not a bug. When an element changes size all the elements in the same layer gets size recalculation and repainted. It is not a bad thing in all cases. To improve performance in certain cases, you need to isolate dynamic elements in separate layers. Here is [a nice article](https://medium.com/masmovil-engineering/layers-layers-layers-be-careful-6838d59c07fa#a02d) about the topic.

Comment: My final question: I found that grid is irrelevant here. But removing `relative` really helps. According to your point, why would `static` vs `relative` positioning have different layer configuration?

Comment: `static` is the default value of the `position` property. The `relative` value tells browser that that the element is to be re-positioned in some way. In this case `relative` is forcing browser to recalculate the following relative elements.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Chrome is grouping parts of your page into larger layers, which normally helps with performance as it has less parts of the page to track. The downside is that if you animate part of one of these layers then the whole layer gets repainted.

The different workarounds are all forcing Chrome to separate out the elements you apply them to into their own smaller layers. There is obviously a performance trade off when you do this. One work around is to only apply these CSS fixes to the element while the transition is running, and then remove it when it has completed.

You might find this article interesting that goes into every detail of things that cause janky rendering.

https://www.sderosiaux.com/articles/2015/03/01/perfmatters/